# Update Kotlin logic from when statement

Tags: kotlin

I have a when statement that checks names of people in an array and return the person. However I now only want it to return the person if their name and age is what I'm searching for. How can I update the code below to do this?

```
when (Person.name) {
                    Name.Amy -> AmyData
                    Name.Patrick -> PatrickData
                }
```

Comment: This heavily depends on what kind of behaviour you want if their name _isn't_ what you're looking for. What should happen in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed you have Person

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

and collections of Person

```
val people = listOf(Person("Amy", 11), Person("Amy", 25), Person("Patrick", 25))
```

than, you can find Amy with age 25 in the collections:

```
val amy25 = people.find { it.name == "Amy" && it.age == 25 }
```